# truncated class file exception when load class from jar

Tags: java

I am trying to read class, stored in my jar file.

When I do like this

```
private void registerClasses(Path jar, List<String> classNames) throws IOException {
    JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(jar.toFile());
    Enumeration<JarEntry> e = jarFile.entries();
    while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
        JarEntry je = e.nextElement();
        if (je.isDirectory() || !je.getName().endsWith(".class")) {
            continue;
        }

        String className = je.getName().substring(0, je.getName().length() - 6).replace('/', '.');
        if (classNames.contains(className)) {
            LOGGER.info("Found class in jar [{}].", className);
            InputStream stream = new JarInputStream(jarFile.getInputStream(je));
            byte[] classBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(stream); // empty array
            Class<?> clz = this.defineClass(className, classBytes, 0, classBytes.length);
            LOGGER.info("Defined class: [{}].", clz.getClass());
        }
    }
}
```

I get `java.lang.ClassFormatError: Truncated class file` and `byteArray` appears to be empty.

What is the problem?

Comment: Are you sure the .class file isn't empty?

Comment: Yes. I provide artifacts built by IDE

Answer (score 0):

I remember running into that problem in the past and remembered the solution for that. I create input stream like this.

```
InputStream stream = new JarInputStream(jarFile.getInputStream(je));
```

But there is no need to create new `JarInputStream` as `getInputStream` already returns `InputStream`. So I changed to this

```
InputStream stream = jarFile.getInputStream(je);
```

And it started to work.